# using Calcite's ReflectiveSchema from scala

Tags: scala, apache-calcite

I'm experimenting with calcite from scala, and trying to pass a simple scala class for creating a schema at runtime (using `ReflectiveSchema`), I'm having some headache.

For example, re-implementing the [FoodMart JDBC Example](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/examples/foodmart/java/JdbcExample.java) (which works well in Java), I'm calling it as simple as `new ReflectiveSchema(new Hr())`, using a `Hr` class rewritten in scala as:

```
class HR {

  val emps: Array[Employee] = Array(new Employee(100, "Bill"))

}
```

I'm experiencing an error: `...SqlValidatorException: Object 'emps' not found within 'hr'`. This problem seems to be related to the fact that `val` fields are actually created `private` in bytecode from java, and the implementation in calcite seems to be able to use (by means of java reflection) only fields accessible through the `.getFields()` method of a class. 
So I suppose this direction requires a lot more hacking than a simple `my_field.setAccessible(true)` or similar.

Are there any other way to construct a schema by API, avoiding reflection and the usage of JSON?

thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/codefeedr/repl/blob/master/src/main/java/HrSchema.java) I found an hybrid approach, where the HRSchema has been actually written in Java, while the [ReflectiveSchema usage](https://github.com/codefeedr/repl/blob/212f7d4e08c7ca118682fff0c34199ced233c629/src/main/scala/commands/ConnectCommand.scala#L45) is in Scala instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This way works for me too, but my concern is about enabling the usage of scala classes itself (or even case classes), otherwise It would be less flexible to use from my code.
Any ideas?